# ExpressJS & Cookies - Cannot get express-cookie to Initialize a Cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I watched a YouTube tutorial (https://youtu.be/hNinO6-bDVM?t=2m33s) where the cookie can be seen in the developer tools `Application` tab once the following code is added to `app.js`:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    name: 'testcookie',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    }
}))
```

However, I'm having no luck in seeing a cookie. I feel like I've tried almost everything, but this is all I'm getting:

[image]

Here is my full `app.js` file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/login');
var createSession = require('./routes/session');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', usersRouter);
app.use('/session', createSession);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    name: 'testcookie',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    },
    proxy: true
}))

module.exports = app;
```

Do you know what could be missing? I'm new to Express and this has been an incredible struggle for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a cookie in `express` while using `cookie-parser` middleware you must provide an **endpoint/route** to supply the cookie. In a route handler add the code

`res.cookie(“myCookieName”, {value: “some-value”})`

And the client will receive the cookie upon visiting that route.

Now on each request the end-user makes the cookie will be sent to your server automatically and parsed with `cookie-parser`. Each cookie we have set can then be accessed by name on the `req.cookie` object while handling it an incoming request in the route handler body.

If you would like to set any options while setting a cookie all options such as `expired` and `maxAge` can be found in the 
`cookie-parser` docs.